# python array.fromfile vs struct.unpack

Tags: python, performance, binaryfiles

I am currently using struct.unpack to read a binary file. Frequently, I would be reading different types of values, so I might read a few longs, then read 8 floats, then read 2 shorts, a couple bytes, etc.

But they are generally grouped nicely so you might get a bunch of longs, and then a bunch of floats, and then a bunch of shorts, etc.

I've read a couple posts about how arrays perform much faster than unpack, but am not sure if there will be a significant difference if I am constantly calling fromfile with different array objects (one for each type I might come across).

Has anyone done any performance tests to compare the two in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are in the best position to do the time trials.  You already have the `struct.unpack` version, so make an `array.fromfile` version and then use the `timeit` module to do some benchmarks.  Something like this:

```
python -m timeit -s "import struct_version" "struct_version.main()"

python -m timeit -s "import array_version" "array_version.main()"
```

where `struct_version` and `array_version` are your two different versions, and `main` is the function that does all the processing.